# Are Hops kosher for passover without certification?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, liquor-beer

Inspired by http://www.toastale.com/toast-ale-recipe/

my idea is instead of using bread to use matzah as the source of fermentable sugars.

The ingredients for modern beer "usually" are malt, water, yeast, and hops

Now assuming I replaced the malt with a chometz free product such as matzah and the yeast was certified kosher for Passover or used spontaneous inoculation. Would the hops be kosher for Passover without kosher certification?

Comment: do you think that would work (I mean, is it actually possible to make beer that way)?

Comment: That would be *gebrokhts*.

Comment: Is this a halchik question or a beer making question?

Comment: Laser123, [1elcome to Mi Yodeya](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! Mi Yodeya is a community of experts on Judaism, not beer-making, so this question - presumably whether a particular concoction would be kosher for Passover - will be a great deal more answerable if you [edit] in more details about the process/recipe you have in mind for producing beer from matza. If you want to know whether a particular recipe *is likely to work*, I recommend trying asking at [Alcohol.SE].

Comment: I have edited it now to be more specific

Comment: The modern baseline definition of beer is: malt (usually barley, sometimes wheat), water, hops, and yeast.  You ask in your title about hops and in the body about substituting matzah for the barley.  Could you please [edit] to clarify both what you're trying to make and what ingredient(s) your question is about?  (By the way, I am pretty skeptical about fermenting matzah, which is what you'd need to do here.)

Comment: The matza would be the "malt" it is made from grain and would have convertible sugars in it. In other words you wouldn't be fermenting the "matza" but the "wort" made from it. From what I understand is unless you are considering gebruchs for the first 7 days then matza can't become chometz....

Comment: I would think the main issue would be how the hops were processed. Technically it's the flowering part of a vine.